# Не работает служба Windows c#

Tags: c#, windows, sql-server, service

Была следующая задача. Сделать службу Windows, которая прослушивает таблицу базы данных и при добавлении новой строки добавляет файл в определенную директорию. Проблема заключается в том, что при запуске службы через пару секунд он останавливается сам. Код класса ChangeWatcher:

```
class ChangeWatcher
    {
        public string message = "";
        private string connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-K0V0O3J\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
        Catalog=Store;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID = sa; Password =;";
        public void startWatching()
        {
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

            ExecuteWatchingQuery();
        }
        public void stopWatching()
        {
            SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
        }
        private void ExecuteWatchingQuery()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(
                    "select Id, Name from dbo.products", connection))
                {
                    var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    sqlDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDatabaseChange);
                    command.ExecuteReader();
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnDatabaseChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs args)
        {
            SqlNotificationInfo info = args.Info;
            if (SqlNotificationInfo.Insert.Equals(info))
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(
                        "select top 1 Id, Name from dbo.products order by ID desc", connection))
                    {
                        SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rd.Read())
                        {
                            message += rd[0] + "\t";
                            message += rd[1] + "\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
                string path = "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\Паттерны\\DatabaseChanges.txt";
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(message);
                }

            }
            ExecuteWatchingQuery();
        }
    }
```

код класса Service1:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        ChangeWatcher watcher;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CanStop = true;
            this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
            this.AutoLog = true;            
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            watcher = new ChangeWatcher();
            Thread watcherThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(watcher.startWatching));
            watcherThread.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            watcher.stopWatching();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

проверил класс ChangeWatcher в консольном приложении и он работает. Не знаю в чем проблема. Буду очень благодарен за помощь!!!

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, вы не слушаете изменения вы про100 запускаете сервис в котором поток выполняет один раз `watcher.startWatching` или

```
connection.Open();
using (var command = new SqlCommand("select Id, Name from dbo.products", connection))
{
   var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command); // создаете объект
   sqlDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDatabaseChange); // байнд метод
   command.ExecuteReader(); // выполняете команду
 } // команда закончилась до свидания, удаляются всё
```

// где поток или объект который будет слушать изменения

Comment: То есть мне надо написать этот участок кода без using?

Comment: почему же? беда не в самом using где лисенер который будет жив и следить за базой?